# How do I find group areas in a 2D int Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an `int[,]` filled with "0" and "1" values. I'm using this to draw a new bitmap and that's working good.

What I'm having problem with, is finding "Empty areas" in that array.

Now, let's take this array as an example:

```
000000000

011101110

010101010

011101110

000000000

000000000

000000111

000000101

000000111
```

How can I find all "rectangles" possible in the empty space (0s Block)?

What I need is to check for blocks of Zeros and find all blocks bigger than X Width and Y Height.

Let's say I'm looking for blocks bigger than 3x3.

```
222000000

222000000

222222

000222

000222
```

This is one of the results possible.

My goal is to find how many empty "Spaces" I have in an image.

Comment: Hi Xibira!  First question, how can you have an `int` of `000000000`? This isn't possible. C# will turn that into `0`.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Considering it's typed as a 2D array, I would presume all those zeroes are 9 separate integers.

Comment: Are all your empty spaces rectangles or can they be more complex?

Comment: yes, each 0 is a integers. This example is a int[,] with 10 x 10 size.

Comment: Empty spaces can be more complex, but i'm looking only for possible rectangles in the area. Where "1" is occuped space and "0" is  empty space